# How do I update a Flask variable with Ajax GET without reloading my page?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, highcharts, flask

I have a Flask webapp running a HighCharts Dynamic html graph. Here's an example of the View.

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/dynamic-update/

The dynamic Y variable uses a random function in this example. However, I want to replace that function with my Python function on the server side. If i try to replace the y variable with my Python function, {{call_me}}, i get a static variable from my server. I want the function to make a GET request and replay the function, so the Y variable becomes updated. I also want this all to update so that the graph function works without reloading the page, causing it to move dynamically like in the fiddle link.

Here's my example flask:

```
@app.route('/dynamic/', methods = ['GET'])
def dynamic ():
    def call_me():
        return myDynamicVar
    return render_template('dynamic.html', call_me=call_me())
```

I know very little about Ajax, so please explain how this would work.
Thank you!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX

Comment: Before addPoint, you can call ajax and load data from extrenal source.